# Is "sweeping collapse" a natural expression?

Tags: word-choice

I know that it is natural to say "sweeping reform", which means a large scale reform. I wonder whether "sweeping collapse" is comprehensible and natural too?

Comment: [Sure it is](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%22sweeping+collapse%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8): *Eastman Kodak Co. is hemorrhaging money, the latest Polaroid to be wounded by the [sweeping collapse](http://www.wired.com/business/2011/11/kodaks-poor-financial-picture/) of the market for analog film.* Voting to close, as there doesn't seem to be much to discuss here, aside from ['yes' & 'yes'](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%22sweeping+collapse%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#q=%22sweeping+collapse%22&rls=en&safe=off&tbm=bks)

Comment: I agree with J.R. In most cases, an adjective is just an adjective. What may be applied to one noun may serve for another. In the case of a cliche, like *sweeping reform*, it may sound odd to you because the stock phrase wasn't applied. But that is not necessarily a bad thing. Think about it.

Answer (score 3):

Not in the UK it wouldn't be. We'd say *sweeping reform*, but are much more likely to say *complete*, *total* or *utter* collapse than sweeping.